# Split one column into multiple column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I’m working on a power bi audit log report file. The file contains a column 'AuditDate'  and it has multiple columns in it. I need to split that column into multiple columns  using sql.

The column has values like this

```
AuditDate
------------
"{""Id"":""44de2468"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2018-08-03T12:30:34"",""Operation"":""ViewReport"",""OrganizationId"":""779558"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""FFFA3DA"",""Workload"":""PowerBI"",""UserId"":""john@abc.com"",""ClientIP"":""9.5.3.26"",""UserAgent"":""Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;"",""Activity"":""ViewReport"",""ItemName"":""Sales"",""WorkSpaceName"":""TeamITO"",""DatasetName"":""Sales1"",""ReportName"":""Sales1"",""WorkspaceId"":""e8eaa0ca"",""ObjectId"":""Sales1"",""DatasetId"":""4c5d-ad45-eb6546"",""ReportId"":""4cb0-99ad-de41b5160c47"",""IsSuccess"":true,""DatapoolRefreshScheduleType"":""None"",""DatapoolType"":""Undefined""}"
```

Basically I need to split this column into

```
id     RecordType      CreationTime    Operaration     OrganizationID  UserType
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
44de2468    20     2018-08-03T12:30:34   ViewReport     779558               0
```

Can anyone help with the sql query for this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sql server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're dealing with a malformed JSON column here. Those double-double quotes are a bother.

If you can clean up the formatting, though, you can just use JSON functions in your query.

First, set up the data (using the data you provided in your other copy of this question,([Split column values into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173169/split-column-values-into-multiple-columns)):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
  RecordType NVARCHAR(20)
  ,AuditDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT @t
  (
    RecordType
    ,AuditDate
  )
VALUES
  ('View', '{""Id"":""44de2468"",""Type"":20,""CreationDate"":""2018-08-23""}')
 ,('Edit', '{""Id"":""44de2467"",""Type"":40,""CreationDate"":""2018-08-24""}')
 ,('Print', '{""Id"":""44de2768"",""Type"":60,""CreationDate"":""2018-05-06""}')
 ,('Delete', '{""Id"":""44de2488"",""Type"":30,""CreationDate"":""2018-07-20""}');
```

Now, clean up the malformed JSONs by replacing the double-double quotes with single double quotes.

```
UPDATE @t
SET AuditDate = REPLACE(AuditDate,'""','"');
```

Validate the JSONs look good.

```
SELECT * FROM @t

--Results:
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| RecordType |                        AuditDate                        |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| View       | {"Id":"44de2468","Type":20,"CreationDate":"2018-08-23"} |
| Edit       | {"Id":"44de2467","Type":40,"CreationDate":"2018-08-24"} |
| Print      | {"Id":"44de2768","Type":60,"CreationDate":"2018-05-06"} |
| Delete     | {"Id":"44de2488","Type":30,"CreationDate":"2018-07-20"} |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then use `JSON_VALUE()` to extract the parts you're interested in.

```
SELECT 
    RecordType
  , JSON_VALUE(AuditDate, '$.Id') AS [Id]
  , JSON_VALUE(AuditDate, '$.Type') AS [Type]
  , JSON_VALUE(AuditDate, '$.CreationDate') AS CreationDate
FROM @t

--Results
+------------+----------+------+--------------+
| RecordType |    Id    | Type | CreationDate |
+------------+----------+------+--------------+
| View       | 44de2468 |   20 | 2018-08-23   |
| Edit       | 44de2467 |   40 | 2018-08-24   |
| Print      | 44de2768 |   60 | 2018-05-06   |
| Delete     | 44de2488 |   30 | 2018-07-20   |
+------------+----------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: You are correct that this seems to be malformed JSON (+1 from my side). But better, because typed was `OPENJSON` in connection with `WITH` (see my answer)

Comment: @Eric,..this will work for me,,thanks.  Another question..i am new to stack overflow..how do we insert dotted lines in the code...and also when i try to type the data in columns n rows..its taking me a lot of time to format it..is there any other simple way to insert the table data..?

Comment: @sateesh, for formatting table data, I use [this handy site](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). For some other really good tips and tools for posting (and where I stole that first link from) check out [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). As for code format, I have Redgate SQL Prompt on my machine and I let that do the heavy lifting, then I just tab over to meet SO's four character indent, copy, and paste. Thanks for asking how to post better. I'm upvoting your question for the curiosity!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple, all you need is a string "splitter" (AKA tokenizer). If you are on SQL 2016+ you can use `STRING_SPLIT`; if you're on a pre-2016 system you can use [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) on 2005+ or [DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) on 2012+. The solution would look like this:

```
DECLARE @AuditDate VARCHAR(8000) = 
'"{""Id"":""44de2468"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2018-08-03T12:30:34"",""Operation"":""ViewReport"",""OrganizationId"":""779558"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""FFFA3DA"",""Workload"":""PowerBI"",""UserId"":""john@abc.com"",""ClientIP"":""9.5.3.26"",""UserAgent"":""Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;"",""Activity"":""ViewReport"",""ItemName"":""Sales"",""WorkSpaceName"":""TeamITO"",""DatasetName"":""Sales1"",""ReportName"":""Sales1"",""WorkspaceId"":""e8eaa0ca"",""ObjectId"":""Sales1"",""DatasetId"":""4c5d-ad45-eb6546"",""ReportId"":""4cb0-99ad-de41b5160c47"",""IsSuccess"":true,""DatapoolRefreshScheduleType"":""None"",""DatapoolType"":""Undefined""}"'

SELECT 
  Id             = MAX(CASE split.attrib WHEN 'ID'             THEN split.val END),
  RecordType     = MAX(CASE split.attrib WHEN 'RecordType'     THEN split.val END),
  CreationTime   = MAX(CASE split.attrib WHEN 'CreationTime'   THEN split.val END),
  Operation      = MAX(CASE split.attrib WHEN 'Operation'      THEN split.val END),
  OrganizationId = MAX(CASE split.attrib WHEN 'OrganizationId' THEN split.val END),
  UserType       = MAX(CASE split.attrib WHEN 'UserType'       THEN split.val END)
FROM
(
  SELECT      attrib = REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(split.value, 1, mid.point-1),'{',''),'"',''),
              val    = REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(split.value, mid.point+1, 8000),'{',''),'"','')
  FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@AuditDate,',') AS split
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':', split.value))) AS mid(point)
  WHERE       REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(split.value, 1, mid.point-1),'{',''),'"','') IN
                ('id','RecordType','CreationTime','Operation','OrganizationID','UserType')
) AS split;
```

**Results:**

```
Id         RecordType  CreationTime          Operation   OrganizationId  UserType
---------- ----------- --------------------- ----------- --------------- ---------
44de2468   20          2018-08-03T12:30:34   ViewReport  779558          0
```

Comment: HI Alan, thanks for quick answer. i will explain what exactly i need. The table has few other columns aswell apart from 'AuditDate'.                                                                      The table looks like this                                                                                                       Recordtype       Operation      Createddate            AuditDate

Comment: the table has 5000+ rows.  so final output should be, if i do select * from 'table'                                                    RecordType   Operationid   Createddate   Id    Recordtype  Creationtime  Operation  etc.. with all rows..

Comment: @sateesh Alan's answer shows you how to add your columns. I think with a little effort, you'll get there. However, if you run into errors, open a new question now that you know what to use to get your end result.

Comment: @sateesh - in addition to what scsimon said ^^^ -- My solution is using a basic "splitter" AKA "tokenizer", APPLY and to better understand and a pivoting techique that I learned about in Jeff Moden's article here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/. Reverse engineer it - play around with the code and it will be easy to modify to do what you need.

Comment: Alan, the OP uses SQL Server 2016 where there is quite some JSON support. This can be solved very easy, see my answer...

Comment: @AlanBurstein ,,thanks..iam able to get what  i needed from this,,

Answer (score 1):

With SQL-Server 2016 this is pretty simple. There is quite some JSON support. Your only problem is, that your string is not correct. Quite obviously there was an engine doubling all internal quotes (an escaping technique).

If this is under your control, you should try to change your column's format to proper JSON. Even better let the writing application supply these audits in a correct JSON format. At least you might add a second column and use a trigger to keep this synchronised. As a last resort you can use `REPLACE` to repair your string:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,'"{','{'),'}"','}'),'""','"');
```

With a lot of rows this might take a while... That's why it's better to keep the format in proper JSON.

Just to show the principles:

```
DECLARE @YourString NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'"{""Id"":""44de2468"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2018-08-03T12:30:34"",""Operation"":""ViewReport"",""OrganizationId"":""779558"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""FFFA3DA"",""Workload"":""PowerBI"",""UserId"":""john@abc.com"",""ClientIP"":""9.5.3.26"",""UserAgent"":""Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;"",""Activity"":""ViewReport"",""ItemName"":""Sales"",""WorkSpaceName"":""TeamITO"",""DatasetName"":""Sales1"",""ReportName"":""Sales1"",""WorkspaceId"":""e8eaa0ca"",""ObjectId"":""Sales1"",""DatasetId"":""4c5d-ad45-eb6546"",""ReportId"":""4cb0-99ad-de41b5160c47"",""IsSuccess"":true,""DatapoolRefreshScheduleType"":""None"",""DatapoolType"":""Undefined""}"';

SET @YourString = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,'"{','{'),'}"','}'),'""','"');
```

Your string will look like this now:

```
{"Id":"44de2468","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2018-08-03T12:30:34","Operation":"ViewReport","OrganizationId":"779558","UserType":0,"UserKey":"FFFA3DA","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"john@abc.com","ClientIP":"9.5.3.26","UserAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;","Activity":"ViewReport","ItemName":"Sales","WorkSpaceName":"TeamITO","DatasetName":"Sales1","ReportName":"Sales1","WorkspaceId":"e8eaa0ca","ObjectId":"Sales1","DatasetId":"4c5d-ad45-eb6546","ReportId":"4cb0-99ad-de41b5160c47","IsSuccess":true,"DatapoolRefreshScheduleType":"None","DatapoolType":"Undefined"}
```

This query will return all your columns as a drived list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@YourString);
```

The result brings back a list with a type hint (while the actual type of "value" is `nvarchar`):

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| key                         | value                         | type |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| Id                          | 44de2468                      | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| RecordType                  | 20                            | 2    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| CreationTime                | 2018-08-03T12:30:34           | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| Operation                   | ViewReport                    | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| OrganizationId              | 779558                        | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| UserType                    | 0                             | 2    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| UserKey                     | FFFA3DA                       | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| Workload                    | PowerBI                       | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| UserId                      | john@abc.com                  | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| ClientIP                    | 9.5.3.26                      | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| UserAgent                   | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| Activity                    | ViewReport                    | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| ItemName                    | Sales                         | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| WorkSpaceName               | TeamITO                       | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| DatasetName                 | Sales1                        | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| ReportName                  | Sales1                        | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| WorkspaceId                 | e8eaa0ca                      | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| ObjectId                    | Sales1                        | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| DatasetId                   | 4c5d-ad45-eb6546              | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| ReportId                    | 4cb0-99ad-de41b5160c47        | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| IsSuccess                   | true                          | 3    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| DatapoolRefreshScheduleType | None                          | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
| DatapoolType                | Undefined                     | 1    |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
```

And even better, you can add a `WITH` clause like here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@YourString)
WITH 
(   
    Id             varchar(200)  '$.Id',  
    RecordType     int           '$.RecordType',  
    CreationTime   datetime      '$.CreationTime'
    --Add all your known columns here...
)
```

Doing so you get your values typed and *side-by-side*

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------+
| Id       | RecordType | CreationTime            |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+
| 44de2468 | 20         | 2018-08-03 12:30:34.000 |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks Shnugo. The format is not in our control, as when we try to export it, it automatically generates this format. But this will do the job.

Comment: @Shnugo, good suggestions regarding trying to fix the data before it lands. Unfortunate that it's out of sateesh's control. +1 from me, though, for trying to head off the problem instead of just dealing with it.